# start with alphabet and finish with digits

Tags: python, regex

I'd like to define a regular expression in python3 where I can extract words that starts with alphabets and finish with digits.

what I've been trying is `r'^[a-z][A-Z].[0-9]$'`

and didn't return any single word.

Comment: can you post some example text you were running it on & what your expected output is?

Comment: @PaulH It's a corpus from biological paper! any biological paper will do! sorry for forgetting to mention the data!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
r'\b[A-Za-z]\w*[0-9]\b'
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/tstaYO/1). This matches words that begin with a letter, have any word characters after, and end in a digit. Notice the word boundaries that match whole words.

As per the [valuable comment below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61758968/start-with-alphabet-and-finish-with-digits/61758999#comment109240195_61758999), consider an alternative:

```
r'\b[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]*[0-9]\b'
```

The `[A-Za-z0-9]*` won't match underscores while `\w` will.

Comment: `\w` will include underscores, which OP didn't specify whether they want those included. Not saying your solution is wrong, but clarification from OP would be needed on that point.

Comment: @mypetlion Indeed. Let's hear from OP. `[a-zA-Z0-9]` can be used otherwise instead of `\w`

Comment: It doesn't matter if "words" means letters only, letters and digits only or a string of word characters. This answer assumes interpretation #1 but it's obvious how `\w+` would be changed to conform with a different interpretation. We could also debate whether it should be `\w*` or `\w+`, but that would be another time-waster. Ryszard, *proof* is perhaps a bit strong. It's like proving a theorem in mathematics by giving two examples where it works. :-)

Comment: This works really well thank you so much!!!!!! and can I ask you what's \b, \w* 's work? thanks a lot

Comment: and can I also ask you why do we have to set a boundary?

Comment: hj, `\w` is a *word character*. It matches a letter (uppercase or lowercase), digit or underscore (`"_"`).  `\b` is called a *word break*. It means that there cannot be a word character on both sides of it. Suppose the regex were `/\bdog\b/` and the string were `"dog doggy hotdog dog dog"`. The first `"dog"` would match be because no word character (or any other) precedes `"d"` and `"g"` is not followed by a word character. `"doggy"` does not match because the first `"g"` is followed by a word character (the second `"g"`), and so on. There are two matches, both `"dog"`.

Comment: ...word breaks are needed to avoid matching, say, `"cannot"` when we want to match `"can"`.  Test your understanding: if your string were `"my_dog_has_fleas"`, would the regex `\b\w+\b` match four strings? If not, what, if anything, would it match?